# Windows 8.1 apps won't open or load

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-store-app

First off, I'm aware of several existing posts that probably deal with same issue, but I think I'm having a unique problem and have tried a lot of things, but to no avail.

(1) Here is my system information

```
OS: Windows 8.1 Enterprise X86
CPU: Corel i3 X64
```

(2) Problem in detail
    (a). Windows apps won't open or load, I can however open WallStreetJournal app, but it wouldn't load the content and it kind of get stuck in there when launched.
    (b). As strange as it may sound, I can still download and install apps from App Store, but it just won't open

(3) Additional info
    (a). This problem arises just recently
    (b). I have turned off Windows automatic update, but I regularly check and install Windows defender updates
    (c). The major desktop apps I'm using are Adobe creative suite cs6. The Illustrator CS6 crashes very often, I don't know why and I don't know if it had anything to do with the app problem I'm having

(4) Things I have tried (but to no avail)
    (a). delete all files located on windows/software distribution
    (b). run sfc /scannow (it reports I have cbs.log file corrupted)
    (c). run Windows store troubleshooter

Thanks

Comment: try all steps from here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2013/10/11/what-to-do-if-your-windows-8-modern-app-fails-to-start.aspx

Comment: Run `chkdsk /r` from an elevated command prompt as Scandalist suggested, and restart Windows. When the disk check has finished, run again the `sfc /scannow` command. If you still get any errors, upload the `CBS.log` file which is usually stored in `C:\Windows\Log\CBS` somewhere (e.g. http://ge.tt/about), and post the resulting link here for further diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks and31415, Scandalist and magicandre1981, I don't how it worked but this really saved my day!! However I would like to know what caused this problem. I have some of my work related files directly located on desktop, so I guess there are many I/O happens there, could this be the culprit of the problem? Any thoughts? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I would first boot windows up with only the essential boot items. This can be accomplished through the task manager under the startup tab. Failing that working refresh the system which will keep your data intact but reload the OS. You will have to reinstall programs from scratch.

You could also try running a chkdsk /R from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but I wouldn't want to refresh my PC unless I have to.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in your Command Prompt

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\WinStore\AppxManifest.XML"
```

and then reopen your App Store.